# Cakephp3 Upload Thumbnail generation with Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to get Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload to work. I have a working page for uploading Audio, but I am trying to make an image gallery with thumbnail generation. Upon submitting my image, I am redirected to the add page with the error "The provided value is invalid
The provided value is invalid" twice below the file upload form. I have attached my ArtworkTable.php and my view for add.

I have tried renaming things, ->AllowEmpty, and adding some database stuff.

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Artwork Model
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Artwork findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 */
class ArtworkTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('artwork');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->getValidator()->allowEmpty('image')->allowEmpty('thumb');
        $this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
            'image' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'dir' => 'image_dir',
                    'size' => 'image_size',
                    'type' => 'image_type'
                ],
                'nameCallback' => function ($table, $entity, $data, $field, $settings) {
                    return strtolower($data['name']);
                },
                'transformer' =>  function ($table, $entity, $data, $field, $settings) {
                    $extension = pathinfo($data['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    // Store the thumbnail in a temporary file
                    $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'upload') . '.' . $extension;

                    // Use the Imagine library to DO THE THING
                    $size = new \Imagine\Image\Box(40, 40);
                    $mode = \Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET;
                    $imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();

                    // Save that modified file to our temp file
                    $imagine->open($data['tmp_name'])
                        ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
                        ->save($tmp);

                    // Now return the original *and* the thumbnail
                    return [
                        $data['tmp_name'] => $data['name'],
                        $tmp => 'thumbnail-' . $data['name'],
                    ];
                },
                'deleteCallback' => function ($path, $entity, $field, $settings) {
                    // When deleting the entity, both the original and the thumbnail will be removed
                    // when keepFilesOnDelete is set to false
                    return [
                        $path . $entity->{$field},
                        $path . 'thumbnail-' . $entity->{$field}
                    ];
                },
                'keepFilesOnDelete' => false
           ]
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('image')
            ->maxLength('image', 255)
            ->requirePresence('image', 'create')
            ->notEmptyFile('image');

        $validator
            ->scalar('thumb')
            ->maxLength('thumb', 255)
            ->allowEmpty('thumb');

        $validator
            ->scalar('title')
            ->maxLength('title', 255)
            ->requirePresence('title', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('title');

        $validator
            ->scalar('description')
            ->requirePresence('description', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('description');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

View for add.ctp

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \App\View\AppView $this
 * @var \App\Model\Entity\Artwork $artwork
 */
?>
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Artwork'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="artwork form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Artwork') ?></legend>
            <?= $this->Form->create($artwork, ['type' => 'file']); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->control('title'); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->control('image', ['type' => 'file']); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->control('description'); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO club. We need to at least have a chance to understand what on earth you are trying to ask. When you are _new_ to something, you should start by reading the documentation, examples and other resources available. Asking such a question here will most likely only bring you down- and close-votes as it is too broad and doesn't show that you have tried anything. As you are also _new_ to Stackoverflow, I suggest that you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and related help pages. 
Thanks.